# What type of enclosure should I use to mount a small network switch in a crawl space?

Tags: data-wiring, crawlspace

I have a small Ethernet switch that I'd like to mount in the entrance corner of my crawl space, where there's plenty of room to stand and electricity.

I'm having a hard time finding one, though. Can someone recommend something for this?

Comment: By "box" do you mean "enclosure"?  If so do you want it sealed or ventilated?  Bug-proof I presume?

Comment: Yes, an enclosure. My main concern is keep critters away from it. I'm conflicted because if I use a sealed enclosure, I worry about overheating and if it's ventilated I worry about moisture in the air. Then again, I have seen entire server racks in the dankest basements that run for years without problems...

Comment: Changed title to use the word enclosure instead of box.

Comment: You could Google "project box vented" for ideas. Throw in some desiccant and, as long as your crawl space is not too damp, you should be good to go.

Comment: I'm a networking guy, and I can't tell you how many times I've had network switches (especially Netgear Gigabit switches, sorry to say) get dangerously hot or even emit smoke before someone pulled the plug.  If that happened out of sight, in a dry crawlspace, it could well burn down your house... so whatever enclosure you choose, please take extraordinary fire precautions!

Comment: @MT_Head - My feelings exactly. The use of enclosures like this have the following reasons for use in descending order 1) provides a fireproof enclosure in case the equipment catches fire. 2) provides a vermin proof safe area. 3) provides a mounting structure for the devices. Which brings us to the last issues. Since it is outside of the living envelope, it will get cold and condense water. How cold does this crawl space get in winter? Devices usually have an environmental humidity/temp spec.

Comment: Temperature: 0ºC to 40ºC (32ºF to 104ºF)
Humidity: 10% - 90%, Non-condensing... IDK how cold it will get down there, but the avg low in our coldest month is 32 F

Comment: This sounds like a "shop for me" type question, which are off topic here. You could try [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/), [google](http://www.google.com/prdhp), or simply taking a walk around your local hardware store (where you might find a sales person who could help find exactly what you need).

Comment: Sounds like, but isn't. I'm not asking for a model #, but the name of a kind of product I might find. For example, my coworker suggested a vented project box with some desiccant, which I haven't even considered. He even made the suggestion without first saying, "YOU SHOULD HAVE SEARCHED GOOGLE OR AMAZON OR WALKED AROUND A HARDWARE STORE BEFORE EVEN CONSIDERING ASKING ME THIS QUESTION!" which is the kind of response I typically get on a stack exchange site.

Comment: @RonnieOverby Maybe you're asking the wrong questions on Stack Exchange sites?  Not *all* questions fit the scope of the sites, it's an unfortunate downside of having sites with specific focused topics.  You shouldn't take this personally, It's just not a good fit for the site (in my opinion). I often find inspiration while wandering aimlessly through the hardware store, so I don't see why this is such a bad suggestion.

Comment: @Tester101 I understand what you're saying and I'm not taking it personally. But hear me out about my experiences with StackExchange. I've had a half way decent run on StackOverflow, so I understand the concept of having a narrowly focused Q&A site. With increasing frequency my experience on just about every StackExchange site is: I have a question, I spend a non-trivial amount of time deciding where and what to ask, forming the post, and I'm immediately met with reasons why I shouldn't have asked there. It's extremely frustrating and I truly believe that SE moderation takes it way too far.

Comment: @RonnieOverby It may seem that way, but you're only looking at it from your perspective as one single user.  If we allow one single user to ask an off topic (or border line off topic) question, we have to let 10,000,000 other users ask off topic questions.  On/Off topic debates are often like legal cases, showing precedent is very important.  Because of this, sites that are just starting out have to be more strict when it comes to defining the scope.  So next time before you post, think "*If the site had 10,000,000 questions similar to this, would I visit it every day?*" .

Comment: @Tester101 Of course you're right. So am I. I would never ask that question of myself. I don't visit to read questions. I visit to ask them.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do, may not be the best idea. Typically networking equipment (and more generally electronic equipment), is best installed in a conditioned space.  Ideally, you'll want a clean, climate controlled location.  A crawl space generally does not fit the bill, and may be the exact opposite of the ideal location.

Some of the features of the enclosure may directly contradict each other in an environment like this, making it difficult and/or expensive to find a solution. For example. The enclosure should be enclosed to prevent dust, dirt, debris, moisture, and bugs from entering. However, you'll need ventilation to prevent overheating.

In a conditioned room, you can typically be sure the equipment will only be exposed to moderate amounts of dust, dirt, moisture, and bugs.  In an unconditioned space; such as a crawl space, all bets are off.  There could be dust and water everywhere, extreme temperature swings, etc. in a crawl space.

It's possible that you're having such difficulty finding an enclosure, because the best solution is to not install the device in this location. Maybe others have attempted this, and concluded that the easiest solution was to install the equipment somewhere else.  Sometimes "[*The only winning move is not to play.*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086567/quotes?qt=qt0453844)"

Comment: You've nearly talked me out of the idea... and then I read Philip Ngai's answer.....

Comment: I have seen this done in some old buildings, along with Ethernet switches put in attics. Leave alone the mourning and environment issues, the maintenance on those switches because a nightmare as access to those spots is not usually very conducive. Try to find a better spot to terminate your wiring and to locate your network switches.

Answer (score 1):

If your equipment generates enough heat that you have to vent it to prevent overheating, it's not going to suffer from condensation.

If your equipment is in danger of condensation, put it in a sealed box, it doesn't need venting.